# How do you include buttons inside a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am pretty new to JavaScript, HTML and CSS and I am creating a game, but I don't know how.

So basically there is a canvas, and I want to create buttons on the canvas so the player can click on the buttons to go to different game modes.

This is what I have already: (well sort of)

```
<canvas id="gameCanv"></canvas>

<button onclick="javascript:easy();" class="easyButton">Easy</button>
<button onclick="javascript:medium();" class="mediumButton">Medium</button>
<button onclick="javascript:hard();" class="hardButton">Hard</button>
```

What I want is to put those buttons inside the canvas, but I don't know how.

Is there a way to put the buttons inside the canvas using CSS, HTML or JavaScript?

Comment: I encourage you to do some reading on CSS positioning, for example here: [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/), [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning). Learn, try and come back to us if you have some specific issues. Hint: You probably want absolute positioning to place the buttons above the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you add to the canvas has to be hand-built. HTML and CSS won't help at all. That's the purpose of canvas - you're escaping HTML and CSS and telling the browser that you want to manage drawing everything yourself - it gives you a lot of power, but at the cost of losing the user-friendly UI tools, the browser provides.

However, maybe you don't need your whole game to be in a canvas. You can make a portion of the game in canvas, or overlay HTML elements on top of the canvas, or you can even build your entire game in HTML and not use canvas at all. It all depends on what your needs are.

Maybe someone else can answer properly how to actually render a custom button in canvas - I'm not extremely familiar with canvas myself. I mostly wanted to point out that this might not actually be what you want, as it sounds like you're wanting to use the power of HTML/CSS. If you do want to go the route of actually creating your own buttons in canvas, I would recommend going through a canvas tutorial like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial), so you're familiar with the ins and outs of using canvas, and will be able to add other things to canvas when the time comes, like a character, background, etc.

If, all you're wanting is to overlay HTML elements on top of canvas (and not put them inside the canvas), then you can do as @barthy suggested and use position absolute (or relative) to move the buttons over the canvas element.